# Can it be shown that there is a unique $R$-Algebra-Homomorphism for any other $R$-Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I want to show that $R[X]/(fX-1)$ is isomorphic to the localization of $R_f:=S^{-1}R$ where $f\in R, S=\{f^n, n\in\mathbb{N}_0\}$

We have previously proved this statement: Let $(A,\gamma)$ be a $R$-Algebra where $\gamma$ sends all Elements in $S$ to units of $A$.

If **for any** $R$-Algebra $(B,\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ sends all Elements in $S$ to units of $B$ there exists a **unique** $R$-Algebra-Homomorphism $A\rightarrow B$, then there is a unique $R$-Algebra-Isomorphism $S^{-1}R\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} A$.

I think this result can be used. If we define the map $\gamma$ which sends every Element in $R$ to its constant polynomial (degree $0$), then its remainder $\mod{(fX-1)}$, we have a map which satisfies the conditions.

Can we now show that for all other $R$-Algebras $(B,\alpha)$ as defined above there that there exists a Homomorphism $A\rightarrow B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $A = R[X]/(fX-1)$. Then, for any other $R$-algebra $B$, we have that:
$$ Hom_R(A,B) = \{\phi \in Hom_R(R[X],B) \textrm{ such that }f\phi(X)-1 = 0 \}$$

By the universal property of polynomial rings, $Hom_R(R[X],B) \simeq B$, and the condition avove amounts to saying that $\phi(X)$ is the inverse of $f$, so $Hom_R(A,B)$ is either empty if $f$ has no inverse in $B$, or contains a unique morphism by uniqueness of  the inverse.

Comment: Could you please expand on why the set $Hom_R(A,B)$ is exactly the set you defined? :)

Comment: Sure: this is a property of quotients. Giving a morphism from a quotient ring $A/I$ to another ring $B$ is the same as giving a morphism $\phi : A\rightarrow B$, which respects the equivalence relation, that is, such that $\phi(x)=0$ for $x\in I$. Here, the ideal being principal, we only require that $\phi(fX-1) = f\phi(X)-1 = 0$.